# How to install .deb file during ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, deb

I would like to know if we can install .deb file during the time of installing OS. We install Ubuntu and during this process I want one of the .deb file to be installed during the time of OS installation.

I want to inject .ko files to Ubuntu installer via Debian packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Comment: @N0rbert The link provided is installing deb package once OS is installed. I want to Inject .ko files to Ubuntu installer via Debian file.

Comment: Use preseeding: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html